# How do you prove that a certain circuit is impossible to construct with a certain amount of switches?

Tags: switches, circuit-theory

I wanted to make a subcircuit, which, if viewed as a black-box, is a two-terminal device, which can behave as

- a closed circuit (0 Ω)
- 25 Ω
- 50 Ω
- an open circuit (∞ Ω)

(sans non-idealities of course; i.e. the closed circuit will be limited to switch resistances, and the open circuit may have some leakage current).

I wanted to use PMOS transistors as switches, and I thought you need two of them: 2 transistors × 2 possible states each, therefore you should be able to make those 4 states listed above, with a clever combination of series/parallel resistors and P-MOSFETs.

I soon realized the circuit is unimplementable with just 2 switches. Even if you stop thinking about transistors and biasing, and employ 2 SPST switches - you just can't do it. You need at least 3 of them.

I guess this touches on circuit complexity theory, but not exactly.

## Question

How do you prove you need at least N switches if you want to generate a subcircuit, which an take on M possible resistance values (assuming you have an unlimited amount of fixed resistors of any values you want?)

This sounds more like a brainteaser, but I'm genuinely interested which branch of EE/math tackles such problems.

Comment: read about switched-capacitor resistors: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched_capacitor

Comment: but wrt to your actual question: you could think about active matrix circuits. those realize independent two-ports (for 2d matrices) with a certain number of switches. Not sure if active matrices are optimal wrt switch count but probably at least pretty good, so they are a good basis for further research

Comment: If you can use fancy switches like a SP3T and a SPST, you can do it with two switches.

Comment: If you must use only binary switches (where only two states are possible), this is possibly related to that a binary tree with 4 leaves (exit states) will always require at least 3 non-leaf nodes (switches)...

Comment: @Aaron, yes the SP3T solves this riddle. But then if you go that slope, you can ask for SP4T and voilà! it's doable with a single switch. Thus I call it cheating :)

Comment: @ManRow, no, I disagree. If the task was to be able to do {0Ω, 25Ω, 50Ω, 75Ω} - that is certainly doable with 2 SPSTs. My gut feeling is that it has to do with the requirement that both 0Ω and ∞Ω are present in the input list.

Comment: @anrieff Interesting I guess as vir mentioned there might be a rule constraining which outputs would be allowed using only two switches. So, perhaps three switches may be required for any four "arbitrary" outputs (where they can be "anything"), but if your outputs are not just arbitrary but somehow related to one another, then you may be able to use less switches in that case....

Comment: @anrieff about you intuition with the infinite impedance: again I suggest you review passive vs active matrix two-port switches. passive matrices have trouble with infinite impedance because of the leakage through the other paths in the matrix. active matrices allow for one or several infinite impedance nodes.

Comment: I *think* you could attack it with the pigeonhole theorem but only for an 'excessive minimum' (i.e. surely not less than 2 but in your case you need 3). Like for a state machine with 4 state you need at least two memory bits (for FSM there are stronger proofs). I agree with complexity and of course combinatorials

Answer (score 2):

I think that here there are two "types" of circuits to think about: switched circuits where there is one current path between the input and output, and switched circuits where more than one current path can be activated.  For M branches, the first type can be implemented with either M SPST switches or x yPDT switches where x is the log base 2 of M, rounded up to the next whole number and y doubles at each successive level.

When multiple current paths can be activated, you have 2^N possible combinations but they cannot be arbitrary.  The response of the circuit when more than one switch is activated MUST be the "sum" of the two switches taken individually.  There is no combination of two terms of 0, 25, 50, and infinity that satisfies this.

Edit: I think there's something in there to consider about SPST vs SPDT switches and "how does an open SPST switch compare to a SPDT switch in terms of binary choice" but maybe this is more a question for the mathematics crowd.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS5Lz8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>